# OR notification in SOLR metadata for facets

Tags: search, solr, search-engine, websphere-commerce

We are working on Apache solr engine integration with IBM WCS. On applying multiple facets on the pages the previous facets will be converted to some encoded form using Base64 algorithm.

i.e When we will apply three facets F1, F2 and F3, first two F1 and F2 will be encoded and added to metaData field of URL param. and third parameter F3 will go into facet param. and those two previous facets F1 and F2 will be AND'ed using some special character in SOLR. That special character is something line below, `<MT@SP>`

`F1 <MT@SP> F2`

May i know what is the similar charater with which i can do logical OR? Like

`F1 OR F2`???????

Comment: What version of WCS are you using, what feature pack?  Is this the version of SOLR that comes with WCS or a standalone version?  Up until at least FP 5 there is no support for logical OR of facets in the WCS version of SOLR.  I am not sure yet of FP6 offers this as a feature.

Comment: Hi Michael, we are using WCS 7 - Feature pack 5 and solr is the one which comes with WCS. if logical OR is not supported in prevoius versions then how come multi-value select work on same facet i.e. if i want apply facet for color with values red and blue both?

Comment: Not sure I understand the comparison, red and blue both is a logical AND, not a logical OR.  SOLR does not support "blue" OR "red", just "blue" AND "red".  Feature pack 5 might support this, but I have not worked with WCS in FP 5 yet.

Comment: Thanks Michael for you valuable response. If i get know about this i will update in this thread.